# Alternatives to the ClickToPlugin Safari extension for Chrome users

Tags: google-chrome, safari, google-chrome-extensions, safari-extensions

I have been using Safari with [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin) and was wondering if there was anything similar for Chrome. I am looking for both the click-through to plugin functionality as well as the HTML5 video replacements.

I've done some looking around the Chrome extensions page and found some specific extensions to help with forcing the HTML5 on YouTube or to block Flash but none seem offer the generic functionality (click-through works for any given plugin) and flexibility that ClickToPlugin does (ClickToPlugin has HTML5 video replacements for a plethora of websites).

I am looking to mimic the aforementioned features in Chrome, but they don't necessarily have to be provided by one single extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome comes with Click to Play built-in. Head over to `chrome://chrome/settings/content#click`, & enable Click to Play

[image]

For HTML5 video replacement, there's a [html5ify](https://github.com/lenniboy/html5ify) but it supports limited sites.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although html5ify didn't work sadly. I tested with YouTube and got a white screen where my video should have been and right-clicking revealed the usual Flash Player menu.

Chrome's build-in click to plugin functionality is great though!

Comment: If _click to play_ is enabled and you're on a website which contains plugins then a puzzle piece with a red x will be displayed in the address bar which let's you easily whitelist the site. Seems to work for iframes too.

Answer (score 1):

That is one thing chrome is missing compared to Safari's ClickToPlugin.
That thing is awesome.
I wish someone could develop an extension for Chrome:
Here is some helpful doc's http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/killers.xhtml